# How to do I search in mongoDB? (I want to pull up low level data)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

First of all, I don't know correct keyword that I want a feature
So, I write this question.

I want to pull up data depth in mongodb
Can I pull up this?

My NoSql Query is below

```
db.test.find({
    InsertedDate: {
        $gt: ISODate("2020-11-09T00:00:00.000Z"),
        $lt: ISODate("2020-11-09T12:00:00.000Z")
    }
}, {
    "HttpDetail.Body": true,
    "HttpDetail.QueryString": true,
    "HttpDetail.UserId": true,
    "InsertedDate": true
})
.limit(3)
.sort({InsertedDate: -1});
```

I update my original document.

```
[
  {
    "_id": {"$oid": "5fa92f269f98260ff81a7aaf"},
    "InsertedDate": {"$date": "2020-11-09T11:59:34.951Z"}
  },
  {
    "_id": {"$oid": "5fa92f269f98260ff81a7aae"},
    "InsertedDate": {"$date": "2020-11-09T11:59:34.950Z"},
    "HttpDetail": {
      "QueryString": "",
      "Body": "",
      "UserId": 103992
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": {"$oid": "5fa92f095660dd0d34eb1fd0"},
    "InsertedDate": {"$date": "2020-11-09T11:59:05.844Z"},
    "HttpDetail": {
      "QueryString": "",
      "Body": "",
      "UserId": 103992
    }
  }
]
```

(My Expectation is below)

```
[
  {
    "_id": {"$oid": "5fa92f269f98260ff81a7aaf"},
    "InsertedDate": {"$date": "2020-11-09T11:59:34.951Z"}
  },
  {
    "_id": {"$oid": "5fa92f269f98260ff81a7aae"},
    "InsertedDate": {"$date": "2020-11-09T11:59:34.950Z"},
    "Body": "",
    "HttpDetail": {
      "QueryString": "",
      "UserId": 103992
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": {"$oid": "5fa92f095660dd0d34eb1fd0"},
    "InsertedDate": {"$date": "2020-11-09T11:59:05.844Z"},
    "Body": "",
    "HttpDetail": {
      "QueryString": "",
      "UserId": 103992
    }
  }
]
```

I can't find it all day long, so I write a question like this.
I can't even think of a keyword to look up.

Comment: Can you post an example of your documents please?

Comment: @J.F. Result item in my question is my result. It is document of result

Comment: But how is the original document? A document inserted into collection, how is the schema?

Comment: @J.F. I updated original document in content

Comment: Well, your expectation is wrong. This is a transformation you’d do in your application code. You *can* apply extensive transformations when using an *aggregation pipeline*, but that might be overkill here.

Comment: @deceze I appreciate your opinion. It's my first time using MongoDB, so I asked if it's possible.